# Compare strings binary (& not alphanumeric)

Tags: string, sorting, compare

How do you compare strings binary (not alphanumeric) ??

Torrent spec:

> Keys must be strings and appear in sorted order (sorted as raw
>   strings, not alphanumerics). The strings should be compared using a
>   binary comparison, not a culture-specific "natural" comparison.

So i need to sort a dict by key... but i dont get this spec.. 
Explanations ..anyone?

Update: acordingly to: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch5lingsort.htm

> Using Binary Sorts
>
> One way to sort character data is based on the numeric values of the
>   characters defined by the character encoding scheme. This is called a
>   binary sort. Binary sorts are the fastest type of sort. They produce
>   reasonable results for the English alphabet because the ASCII and
>   EBCDIC standards define the letters A to Z in ascending numeric value.
>
> Note: In the ASCII standard, all uppercase letters appear before any
>   lowercase letters. In the EBCDIC standard, the opposite is true: all
>   lowercase letters appear before any uppercase letters.
>
> When characters used in other languages are present, a binary sort
>   usually does not produce reasonable results. For example, an ascending
>   ORDER BY query returns the character strings ABC, ABZ, BCD, ÄBC, when
>   Ä has a higher numeric value than B in the character encoding scheme.
>   A binary sort is not usually linguistically meaningful for Asian
>   languages that use ideographic characters.

So basically it the same result for english as alfabetically sorting.. 
Nice..

Comment: c#.. (or java if you fancy it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any standard sort routine should work, as long as you ensure the characters are treated as bytes.